# From the equation $\sigma(x^{\varphi(y)})=\frac{1}{\varphi(x)}(x^y-1)$ involving arithmetic functions to a characterization of Sophie Germain primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility, totient-function, divisor-sum

In this post we denote the Euler's totient function that counts the number of positive integers $1\leq k\leq n$ such that $\gcd(k,n)=1$ as $\varphi(n)$, and the sum of divisors function $\sum_{1\leq d\mid n}d$ as $\sigma(n)$. As reference I add the Wikipedia [*Sophie Germain prime*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophie_Germain_prime) that provides the well-known definition that a prime $p$ is a Sophie Germain prime if $2p + 1$ is also prime. This prime constellation corresponds to the entry *A005384* from the OEIS.

From previous definition and the calculations of previous arithmetic function $\varphi(n)$ and $\sigma(n)$ it is easy to check the proof of the following claim.

**Claim.** *If* $x=p$ *is a prime such that* $y=2p+1$ *is also prime, then* $(x,y)$ *solves the equation* $$\sigma(x^{\varphi(y)})=\frac{1}{\varphi(x)}(x^y-1).\tag{1}$$

We propose the following conjecture inspired in previous claim, from the substitution $$y=x+\sigma(x).\tag{2}$$

**Conjecture.** *Let* $S\geq 1$ *be an integer that satisfies* $$1+\varphi(S)\sigma(S^{\varphi(S+\sigma(S))})=S^{S+\sigma(S)},\tag{3}$$
*then* $S$ *is a Sophie Germain prime.*

The motivation of this question is try to get a characterization of this prime constellation, Sophie Germain primes, in terms of the important number theoretic functions $\sigma(n)$ and $\varphi(n)$ encoded in an equation relating those. Are known the importance of Sophie Germain primes, and on the other hand also inequalities involving the mentioned number theoretic functions.

> **Question.** What work can be done with the purpose to prove or refute previous **Conjecture**? **Many thanks.**

**Computational evidence.**  You can check in the web *Sage Cell Server* this line written in Pari/GP

`for(x=1, 1559, if(1+eulerphi(x)*sigma(x^eulerphi(x+sigma(x)))==x^(x+sigma(x)),print(x)))`

just copy and paste it to evaluate in the web choosing as Language the option *GP*.

The following, and similar scripts that I can to evaluate `for(x=1, 5000, if((isprime(x)==0||isprime(2*x+1)==0)&&1+eulerphi(x)*sigma(x^eulerphi(x+sigma(x)))==x^(x+sigma(x)),print(x)))`don't show outputs as counterexamples.

Comment: Again using the same (analogous) proof from the answer, one can to get a characterization for twin primes (I mean from the OEIS *A001359 Lesser of twin primes*): *A prime* $B$ *is the lesser of twin primes* ($B$ is prime such that $B+2$ is also prime) *if and only if* $\sigma(B^{\,\varphi(1+\sigma(B\,))})=\frac{1}{\varphi(B)}\left(B^{1+\sigma(B\,)}-1\right)$ *holds.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nice question! Assume that $p^2 \mid S$. This would then give $p \mid \varphi(S)$. However, this is impossible in our case since:
$$p \mid S^{S+\sigma(S)}-\varphi(S)\sigma(S^{\varphi(S+\sigma(S))}) \implies p \mid 1$$
which is clearly false.

Since $S$ is square-free, let:
$$S=\prod_{i=1}^n p_i$$
for distinct primes $p_1,p_2, \ldots ,p_n$. Then, by substitution:
$$1+\varphi(\prod p_i)\sigma(\prod p_i^{\varphi(S+\sigma(S))})=\prod p_i^{S+\sigma(S)}$$

$$1+\bigg(\prod (p_i-1)\bigg)\bigg(\prod \frac{p_i^{\varphi(S+\sigma(S))+1}-1}{p_i-1}\bigg)=\prod p_i^{S+\sigma(S)}$$

$$\bigg(\prod (p_i^{\varphi(S+\sigma(S))+1}-1)\bigg)=\bigg(\prod p_i^{S+\sigma(S)}\bigg)-1$$

But, we have:

$$\bigg(\prod (p_i^{\varphi(S+\sigma(S))+1}-1)\bigg) \leqslant \bigg(\prod (p_i^{S+\sigma(S)}-1)\bigg) \leqslant \bigg(\prod p_i^{S+\sigma(S)}\bigg)-1$$

We need equality in both places. The first equality can only hold true when $S+\sigma(S)$ is prime, so that $\varphi(S+\sigma(S))+1=S+\sigma(S)$. The second inequality can hold true only when there is one term in the product, i.e. $n=1$.

Since $N=1$, $S$ is prime. This shows that $S+\sigma(S)=2S+1$ is prime. Hence, $S$ is a Sophie-Germain prime, proving your conjecture to be true!

Comment: @user759001 I really liked your question! +1 from me! If any part of my answer is unclear, please let me know so that I can clarify. I would really be interested to discuss more about this question with you in a chatroom, if you are fine with that.

Comment: Tomorrow in the morning I'm going to study your nice answer. On the other hand always I prefer add details in the genuine posts instead in chat rooms. I'm not a professional mathematician and I do this since I like mathematics, from this point of view I would like to dedicate this post and the (yours) statement to you. Many thanks again.